# Learning to Scrape and Getting Kernel_Require Errors

Tags: kernel, screen-scraping

So I am learning to scrape websites and validate links but I keep getting the following error:

> /Users/macuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in
>   `require':
>   /Users/macuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rubyful_soup-1.0.4/lib/rubyful_soup.rb:233:
>   syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'
>   (SyntaxError)
>   /Users/macuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rubyful_soup-1.0.4/lib/rubyful_soup.rb:426:
>   syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input  from
>   /Users/macuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in`
>   rescue in require'   from
>   /Users/macuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'    from linkValidator.rb:3:in`'

I downloaded rubyful_soup with the gem install command, but it looks to be like some kind of deprecated code that I don't know that I'm using. Here is the code:

```
require 'uri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'rubyful_soup'

begin
  print "\n\nEnter website to crawl (ex. http://www.google.com): "
  url = gets
  puts url
  uri = URI.parse(url)
html = open(uri).read
rescue Exception => e
  print "Unable to connect to the url:"
  puts "ERROR - - - - #{e}"
end

soup = BeautifulSoup.new(html)

links = soup.find_all('a').map { |a| a['href'] }

links.delete_if { |href| href =~ /javascript|mailto/ }

links.each do |l|
  if l
    begin
      link = URI.parse(l)
      link.scheme ||= 'http'
      link.host ||= uri.host
      link.path = uri.path + link.path unless link.path[0] == //
      link = URI.parse(link.to_s)

      open(link).read
    rescue Exception => e
      puts "#{link} failed because #{e}"
    end
  end
end
```

Any suggestions would be ever much appreciated.

Thanks so much in advance.

-T

Comment: That gem is not being maintained anymore. You should probably be using Nokogiri.

Comment: Thank you so much Pguardiario! You are so awesome!!